# Get a list of registered domains in AWS Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I manage my domains in Amazon Web Services Route53 and trying to get a full list of my registered domains (100+), but I am not able to find this option either in AWS console nor on the command line interface.

I'd be happy with any output format, csv, json, xml, whatever, just need to have a complete list as I don't want to copy them one by one.
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After looking for it for 3 hours I found that AWS Route 53 service uses the **us-east-1** endpoint only. As I used

> aws configure

to setup the AWS CLI, in my *~/.aws/config* file I had **region=eu-west-2** defined as default region.

Defining the endpoint to use has done the magic:

> aws route53domains list-domains --region us-east-1

Comment: Correct. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#r53_region

Answer (score 0):

This AWS-CLI command should work:

```
aws route53domains list-domains
```

Comment: I get the error  "Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://route53domains.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/" . Checked on the Health Dashboard that the service is working.

Comment: You need to make sure you CLI is setup and functioning properly, i.e. run "aws configure" and make sure you can execute some other commands; that error usually means a problem with your credentials.

Comment: I think my CLI is setup properly, I am able to run other commands, ie. create hosted zones, add DNS records, etc. I have run "aws configure".